# How can I make the 'rustdoc::broken_intra_doc_links' lint an error from the command line

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

Rustdoc has a lint called `rustdoc::broken_intra_doc_links` for checking doc status. I would like to make this lint into an error via command line flags. Most rust lints can be configured via `-D flags` but I can't figure out how to do it for rustdoc, even when invoking it explicitly on the command line. I tried for example

`cargo rustdoc -p mycrate -- -D "rustdoc::broken_intra_doc_links"`

but this just gives me the error `error[E0602]: unknown lint: 'broken_intra_doc_links'`

I am aware that I can put `#![deny(rustdoc::broken_intra_doc_links)]` into the code to flag this, I don't wish to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, lints on the command line use dashes, but they use underscores when written as part of the file, whether for rustdoc, clippy, or otherwise.  So this should work, and something similar appears to work for me on the command line:

```
$ cargo rustdoc -p mycrate -- -D rustdoc::broken-intra-doc-links
```

Comment: Thanks, can’t believe I forgot that!

Incidentally, do you happen to know where there's a way to make it run on all crates in a workspace? It’s a little tedious to need to do `-p crate` for every crate